# Separate frontend and backend with Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment

I have an application, let's call it derpshow, that consists of two repositories, one for the frontend and one for the backend.

I would like to deploy these using Heroku, and preferably on the same domain. I would also like to use pipelines for both parts separate, with a staging and production environment for each.

Is it possible to get both apps running on the same domain, so that the frontend can call the backend on `/api/*`? Another option would be to serve the backend on `api.derpshow.com` and the frontend on `app.derpshow.com` but that complicates security somewhat.

What are the best practices for this? The frontend is simply static files, so it could even be served from S3 or similar, but I still need the staging and production environments and automatic testing and so and so forth.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You want to use Heroku for what ?

Comment: What are the technologies for the frontend and backend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For what you are trying to you must use webserver for serving static content and provide access to container(gunicorn, tomcat, etc...) holding your app. Also this is best practice.

Asume your use nginx as webserver, because its easier to setup. nginx config file would look like this

```
# Server definition for project A
server {
    listen             80;
    server_name        derpshow.com www.derpshow.com;

    location / {
        # Proxy to gUnicorn.
        proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:<projectA port>;
        # etc...
    }
}

# Server definition for project B
server {
    listen             80;
    server_name        api.derpshow.com www.api.derpshow.com;

    location / {
        # Proxy to gUnicorn on a different port.
        proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:<projectBg port>;
        allow   127.0.0.1;
        deny    all;
        # etc...
    }
}
```

And thats it.

**OLD ANSWER:** Try using [nginx-buildpack](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/nginx-buildpack) it allows you to run NGINX in front of your app server on Heroku. Then you need to run your apps on different ports and setup one port to api.derpshow.com and other to app.derpshow.com, and then you can restrict calls to api.derpshow.com only from localhost.

Comment: This is a nice sketch of an answer but if you want the bounty I'd appreciate you being a bit more explicit with your instructions. Also, since he asks for best practices, are there other approaches that work or is the best practice really "use nginx"?

Answer (score 4):

Would just like to contribute what I recently did. I had a NodeJS w/ Express  backend and a plain old Bootstrap/vanilla frontend (using just `XMLHttpRequest` to communicate). To connect these two, you can simply tell express to serve static files (i.e. serve requests to /index.html, /img/pic1.png) etc.

For example, to tell express to serve the assets in directory test_site1, simply do:

`app.use(express.static('<any-directory>/test_site1'));`

Many thanks to this post for the idea: https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/deploying-a-react-app-with-a-server/

Note that all these answers appear to be variations of merging the code to be served by one monolith server.

Jozef's answer appears to be adding an entire nginx server on top of everything (both the frontend and backend) to reverse proxy requests.

My answer is about letting your backend server serve frontend requests; I am sure there is also a way to let the frontend server serve backend requests.

Comment: yes but how do you send info to the express server.. ?? 
`xhttp.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/domainfinder/domain/' + dataHere, true);`
how do you set the port & host in your frontend to match the one on express? So that they get set right on heroku

Comment: I don't work in web too much these days, but from what I remember, this involves doing some config stuff. Something along the lines of setting a baseUrl that comes from Heroku config. Of course, when you are testing locally, you can use a DEV config, like localhost and ngrok